# How to create a content Uri for intending ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso, android-testing

I try to write an Android Instrumentation test where a user has to select a folder to save some files to.
But I don't know how to create the result required for `intending`.

The following code is what I came up with until yet.

```
val testUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads")
val openDocumentTreeResult = 
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, testUri)

openDocumentTreeResult.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE))
    .respondWith(
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, openDocumentTreeResult
     )
)
```

Of course the use of `Uri.parse` to create a content Uri is a bit naive. In the logs I have the following warning (probably caused by `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` using the above naive Uri):

```
W/DocumentFile: Failed query: java.lang.SecurityException: 
Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{edb1c64 4157:xyz.com.abc/u0a87} (pid=4157, uid=10087) 
requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

and later on `DocumentFile.createFile()` fails by giving me a null. The corresponding code:

```
val treeUri = intent.data
val pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri)
val target = pickedDir.createFile(mimetype, f.name)
```

When I manually test this scenario first, the test runs then without error. I guess because then my app already has the permission for the downloads directory.

How do I create a result intent for intending which includes the necessary permission.

Comment: "Of course the use of Uri.parse is a bit naive and results in a warning" -- you should not be getting that message from `Uri.parse()` itself. Something using that `Uri` might give you that message, though. "How do I create a result intent for intending which includes the necessray permission" -- you would need to use a `Uri` that you control, to a provider that implements `DocumentsContract` (if you expect `createFile()` on `DocumentFile` to work).

Comment: @CommonsWare the warning was not from the `Uri.parse()`, that was written wrong by me. I guess it came from `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri`. I updated the question.

Comment: @tobltobs Did you find a solution? For an Android instrumentation test I'm trying to make my app mock a tree Uri retrieved from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to return a `Uri` that you want `DocumentFile` to be able to use, the `Uri` has to work. It will need to point to a `ContentProvider` that:

- Exists
- Complies with the `DocumentsContract` API that `DocumentFile` will be calling (or at least the parts of it that you need for your test)
- Returns what you want for your tests

In terms of permissions... ideally, your test provider would not require any, just to simplify matters. If that is impractical, you can try `addFlags()` on your `Intent` to grant what you need (e.g., `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`), though I do not know how well that works in your Espresso test scenario.